# Bayesian inference, finding unknown function of parameter

Tags: self-study, bayesian, inference, prior, normalizing-constant

I'm completely new to Baayesian statistics and am having some questioning about the following:

Given a probability distribution defined by the pdf

$\pi(x|\theta) = C(\theta)x^2 e^{-\theta x^{3}}$ for $x \in [0, \inf)$ and for all $\theta > 0$, determine the function $C(\theta)$

I also know that

$\pi(x|\theta) \propto x^2 e^{-\theta x^3}$

Now this is in a bayesian setting and I was considering Bayes formula

$\pi(\theta|x) = \frac{\pi(\theta)\pi(x|\theta)}{\pi(x)}$ and rewriting it as $\pi(x|\theta) = \frac{\pi(x)\pi(\theta|x)}{\pi(\theta)}$

Where $\pi(\theta)$ would then be the prior, $\pi(x|\theta)$ the "likelihood" and $\pi(\theta|x)$ the posterior. So as I understand it, finding $C(\theta)$ would be similar to finding the normalizing constant in Bayes formula seeing as $C(\theta) = 1/\pi(\theta)$ and $x^2 e^{-\theta x^3} = \pi(x)\pi(\theta|x)$, but following the same procedure with finding the marginal density would mean to find the integral

$\int_{0}^{\infty} x^2 e^{-\theta x^3} dx = \pi(\theta)$

But I don't know if it's even possible to find a closed form of this integral so it feels like I am on the wrong track?

Comment: Is this a question from a course or textbook? If so, please add the `[self-study]`
tag & read its [wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: For finding closed form integrals you can always (well, not in closed-books exams...) try a [computer algebra system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_algebra_system) with symbolic integration. WolframAlpha is available online, try http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+x%5E2+exp(-theta+x%5E3)+from+0+to+infinity

Answer (score 2):

You just need to solve the integral 
$$ \int_{0}^{\infty}\pi(x|\theta)dx=\int_{0}^{\infty}C(\theta)x^2e^{-\theta x^3} dx=1  , \forall \theta > 0 $$

$$=C(\theta) \int_{0}^{\infty}x^2e^{-\theta x^3} dx=1 $$
Letting  $-\theta x^3 =u$ then $\frac{\mathrm{d} u}{\mathrm{d} x} = -3\theta x^2$, this implies 
$$C(\theta) \int_{0}^{-\infty}x^2e^{u} \frac{du}{-3\theta x^2}=1$$
$$C(\theta)\frac{1}{3\theta }\int_{-\infty}^{0}e^{u} du=1$$
$$C(\theta)=3\theta$$

Comment: Ah, of course... Thank you! Need to do some repetition in calculus I notice.